# CSS - how to fix first <td> in table on top if the second <td> is multiline?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

In this code below you will see the "Upload image" text in first `td` has moved down (because of multiline input in next `td`).  But I want is this text to be fixed at the top. 
How can I do it?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Upload Image </td>
    <td> <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
      <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
      <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
      <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use `vertical-align: top` to td.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top` to the `td` with text - see demo below:

```css
table tr > td:first-child {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Upload Image</td>
    <td>
      <input type="file" name="images[]" />
      <br>
      <input type="file" name="images[]" />
      <br>
      <input type="file" name="images[]" />
      <br>
      <input type="file" name="images[]" />
      <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using below code you can achieve that Upload Image in top of first row

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" valign="top"> Upload Image </td>
    <td> <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
         <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
         <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
         <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you need this?

```
<table>
<tr style="display:flex;">
<td style="flex:1;"> Upload Image </td>
<td> <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
     <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
     <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
     <input type="file" name="images[]" /> <br>
</td>
```